# How can Kubernete auto scale nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernete to manage docker cluster. Right now, I can set up POD autoscale using Horizontal Pod Scaler, that is fine.
And now I think the next step is to autoscale nodes. I think for HPA, the auto-created pod is only started in the already created nodes, but if all the available nodes are utilized and no available resource for any more pods, I think the next step is to automatically create node and have node join the k8s master.
I googled a lot and there are very limited resources to introduce this topic.
Can anyone please point me to any resource how to implement this requirement.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do using AWS and setting up your own Kubernetes cluster is by following these steps :

1. Create an Instance greater than t2.micro (will be master node).
2. Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using some tools like Kubeadm. After the initialisation would be completed you would get a join command, which needs to e run on all the nodes who want to join the cluster. ([Here is the link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/))
3. Now create an Autoscaling Group on AWS with start/boot script containing that join command.
4. Now whenever the utilisation specified by you in autoscaling group is breached the scaling would happen and the node(s) would automatically join the Kubernetes cluster.  This would allow the Kubernetes to schedule pods on the newly joined nodes based on the HPA.

(I would suggest to use Flannel as pod network as it automatically removes the node from Kubernetes cluster when it is not available)

Comment: Very useful, but for point 3, I don't know if you can help to show me some more helpful information? For a newly created VM in AWS, I think we still need to manually install such as docker, kubernete software etc,and then run the command to join to master. How can we make it automatic?

Comment: Yes True! You need to run all those. You can create a start bash script containg all the required dependencies along with the join command and add it into the user-data field while VM creation. Here is the link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Thanks, let's say we already have the script to create VM, but when to call this script to create node? do we need to have special setting in Kubernete besides HPA settings? But that is mostly for pod, not for nodes. also, when to destroy?

Comment: This scripts will be the start-script for a node.But the node/VM creation/deletion  would happen based on the Autoscaling group policies. So whenever threnode will be created the start script would run and automatically join Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: what technology do you suggest to run cluster autoscaler? I am looking for generic solutions, not depends on specific cloud providers, such as aws/google cloud etc.

Comment: Step 3 is the hard part - the join commands has a token that is only valid for a few hours and that needs to be obtained from the control-plane node... There might be other options for the node to authenticate itself to the cluster though...

Answer (score 0):

> [kubernetes operations](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) (kops)  helps you create, destroy, upgrade and maintain production-grade, highly available, Kubernetes clusters from the command line.
>
> Features:
>
> - Automates the provisioning of Kubernetes clusters in AWS and GCE
> - Deploys Highly Available (HA) Kubernetes Masters

Most of the managed kubernetes service providers provide auto scaling feature of the nodes

**Elastic Kubernetes Service** [EKS- configure cluster auto scalar](https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_ca/)

**Google Kubernetes Engine**
[GKE Auto Scalar](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)

Answer (score 0):

Auto scaling feature needs to be supported by the underlying cloud provider.  Google cloud supports auto scaling during cluster creation or update by passing flags **--enable-autoscaling** **--min-nodes** and **--max-nodes** to the corresponding gcloud commands.

```
Examples:

gcloud container clusters create mytestcluster --zone=us-central1-b --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes=3 --max-nodes=10 --num-nodes=5
gcloud container clusters update mytestcluster --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes=1 --max-nodes=15
```

below link would be helpful

https://medium.com/kubecost/understanding-kubernetes-cluster-autoscaling-675099a1db92